# Is there any way that I can make android app with version less than 4.0 on new android studio

Tags: android, android-version

I am trying to make an android app and I have installed the latest version of android studio. When I create new project, the API levels are above 4.0 which wont work on many android devices so is there anyway that I can choose another API level?

Comment: Don't program for Android 4 or lower... So bad decision in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

After the project was created, just edit the *build.gradle* to contain

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    //noinspection MinSdkTooLow
    minSdkVersion 9

    ...
}
```

But you should be aware that many current libraries will not support this SDK level.

Also you shouldn't be worried about the devices not being supported with a minimum SDK level of 14. Not too many users actually use these nowadays. Also these are long outdated and insecure.

Comment: When I change the minSDK version this error shows up "Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0] C:\Users\miki\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\37ec02f661e3547c5499ecdfd9f3cd1f\appcompat-1.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 9
 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 9,
  or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 14,
  or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.appcompat" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)"

Comment: Like stated: But you should be aware that many current libraries will not support this SDK level. If you want to use _AndroidX_ libraries you must have it set to 14. Compatibilty to something below is not supported anymore.